# Laravel update to version 9 but get problem with composer require ext-ioncube-loader

Tags: php, laravel, docker, composer-php, ioncube

I have a requirement in composer.json:
"ext-ioncube-loader": "*"

but when I update the others package, it alert me with error:
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-ioncube-loader * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's ioncube-loader extension.

I use the docker to run this but I dont know how to do.

I try to run composer with --ignore-platform-req=ext-ioncube-loader but it also alert:
Script @php ./vendor/bin/testbench package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 199

Comment: Which other packages did you update? How did you install Ioncube in the first place?

Comment: I update the illuminate/support to version ^9.0 (My company project use laravel8 and updating to laravel9), but now i found the problem. It is beacuse i use the wrong environment that is not include the setting (with docker).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because, i used the wrong composer builder (without the ioncube)